# Error while trying to debug Xamarin app iPhone. MT1007: Failed to launch the application:Invalid Service Error (error: 0xe8000022)

Tags: xcode, debugging, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug my xamarin.iOS application in my iPhone.

Visual studio 2022 17.7.4
Xamarin iOS : 16.4.0.15
xCode : 13.3.1
mac OS: Monterey 12.6.7
iPhone version (where the app is to be debugged) : iphone 12, 16.6.1
Developer mode is enabled in iphone.

error MT1007: Failed to launch the application Invalid Service Error (error: 0xe8000022) 0

The application is deployed and am able to open it manually. But I am not able to debug.
I know xCode is quite an old version but I am not able to install newer one because of older mac version.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: The issue is that the app can be installed and opened but doesn’t start with VS debugger, you can follow up there: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-1774----Error-MT1007:-Failed-to-lau/10473921?sort=active&topics=windows+10.0